# IS the site supposed to look like this?

Tags: discussion

Is the site supposed to look like this?

I would have asked on meta but I don't have enough karma.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLMZD.jpg

This is in upto date Chrome, on Linux, with images turned off.  It is not ideal.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it's supposed to look like that. Refusing to load the image bits is your choice and is quite likely to produce non-functional results on most web-sites. If you want it to look right load all the parts (note that Javascript is also required).

If you want a usable text-only template use the mobile site (see the link at the bottom of any page).

Comment: Well it's not just the image bits that he's refusing to load. Some of the CSS looks funky too.

Comment: The contrast is terrible.  I should not have to load images to get readable text.  "Refusing to load the image bits is your choice" - this is terrible usability. Some people are behind image caches and or have otherwise slow loading images. The site should be *readable*, even if not usable, without images.

Comment: There's a good mobile app. No images to disable. Problem solved.

Comment: @BiologicalFather That's rubbish. And I say that not as some Joe Blow off the Internet—I've implemented things like browser feature detection libraries. Sure, the CSS is sub-optimal without the images. But this template is only targeted at fully functional modern browsers. Your "behind caches or slow loading" is nonsense. The images _should be_ cached and they only have to load once. Only if you disable all caches in your chain and have a too slow connection would that be a problem (again user fault). **If you want a fully functional fast loading image-free solution use the mobile template.**

Comment: @Caleb the mobile template unfortunately isn't fully functional in all mobile browsers as all the voting buttons are custom fonts. On my phone they appear invisible :(

Comment: @Caleb - the site should be *readable* without needing images. Most users will not have accounts and will not need the vote buttons and flags and so on.  But they will need to read the text.  I'm surprised at the hostile response to a sensible suggestion -- needing to load images for the text to be readable is clearly sub-optimal.